# How to use <foreignobject> in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, internet-explorer-9

I can use for `<foreignobject>` in SVG. It supports Firefox 14, Safari. But its doesn't support IE9. My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sAnwv/). How to use `<foreignobject>` in IE 9? Or any other way to use in HTML element in SVG.

Answer (score 3):

IE9 does not support [foreignObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28SVG%29) What you could do is create an html or xhtml page and then embed the svg you need in that. Kind of the reverse of what you're doing now.